# Only show users content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I use Devise to let users log in through Facebook or create an acount on my website. When they are logged in they can add movies to their frontpage, the problem is that every user sees all the movies and not just the movies they added.

In my movies_controller.rb I have,

```
def index
  respond_with Movie.all
end
```

My movie.rb model has

```
belongs_to :user
```

And my user.rb model has

```
has_many :movies
```

Two questions, at the moment I'm using `Movie.all` which obviously shows all movies, what would be the correct syntax for showing only the movies the user created. Second question, do I need to insert the users id into the movie record?

I use Angular as my front-end framework,

the controller,

```
  $scope.addMovie = function() {
    movies.create({
      title: $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.title').text()
    }).then(init);
  };
```

And the service,

```
.factory('movies', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    create: function(movie){
      return $http.post('/movies.json', movie);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: `current_user.movies` will load the currently logged in user's movies. Yes, you need to add a column named `user_id` to your `Movie` model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your index method you are fetching all movies. Try fetch only current_user movies.

```
def index
  respond_with current_user.movies
end
```

For second question : You should add user_id in movies table. Otherwise you can't get user's movie list.

As a database standard `belongs_to :xyz` should always present in db as `xyz_id` to get all child records.

Comment: That fixed it. To clarify I allreadu had `user_id` collum in my movies table, but I was wondering if I would need to save the id to the movie, but it seems rails/devise does this itself.

Answer (score 2):

As Dipak suggested you can get 
  1. all the movies from  **Movie.all** 
  2. current user the movies from  **Movie.all** 
u definetly need user id in **Movies** for relating the movies with user